# Java Eclipse debugging: tracking inherited class var

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Am working with a fairly large body of Java code with extensive use of Swing. Somewhere in the depths of the code a JScrollPane is getting changed in a way that gives it a non-zero height and width. I need to locate that but I am stymied as to where it's happening.

Tried setting access & modification watches on the relevant JScrollPane var, but wound up with too many hits. Cut this down to just modifications, but this does not seem to catch the change to the height/width of the Pane.

Tried putting a watch on the height property of JScrollPane, but this var is inherited from Component, which means I get waaay too many hits.

Tried googling, but no luck.

Question: is there a way to set a watch on the height property of the JScrollPane instance, i.e., have it break only on changes to the height of a JScrollPane, not on changes to a height of any other type it inherits from?

Or if I am simply confused and there is a better way to find the relevant section of code, by all means please unconfuse me.

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a breakpoint to `Component.reshape()` and then [setting a condition](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fbreakpoints%2Fref-condition_option.htm) on that breakpoint. For starters, try a condition expression that checks the class of the current instance, something like

```
this instanceof JScrollPane
```

It's not guranteed to work, since it might be possible for something to set the height without going through `reshape()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get a compile time error msg: "Unable to compile conditional breakpoint - missing Java project context". I tried augmenting it to read   javax.swing.JScrollPane  but this didn't help. What am I missing?  tnx.

Comment: How did you open the `Component` class? Try going to some of your code that references `Component` and use F3 to open it; that way you know for sure it's in your project's context.

Comment: Thanks again. Haven't previously done what you suggest, so I may be confused. My code references JScrollPane, which in turn inherits from JComponent, Container, and then Component. When I OpenTypeHiearchy on JScrollPane in my code, I see that hierarchy, and can select the reshape method from Component by going a few levels up. Have set the breakpoint on it, but without success. Should I be doing something else? tnx.

Comment: That sounds right, but like I said there's no guarantee that whatever is affecting the height is going through that method. You could try calling `setBounds()` on your `JScrollPane` directly to see if the breakpoint is hit, just to check that it's working as expected.